# Electron save a part of dom as corel draw file

Tags: angularjs, electron, coreldraw

So I got a task to make an application for windows, to generate a crossword and save it as a corel draw file (.cdr), as I use web technologies I don't know any other way than Electron. So my question is, is it possible to achieve this goal with electron ? Do I need any existing node modules for this saving it as a corel draw file? I would appreciate any kind of information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using the node module [fs (fileSystem)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) you can write anything to disk. So as long as you know the format requirements for a valid .cdr, you will be able to do what you want.